# jQuery plugin: Colorpicker onHide Event

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ and binding the color picker to a class so there are potentially hundreds of color pickers.

I edited the plugins change event to return the element
From:

```
cal.data('colorpicker').onChange.apply(cal, [col, HSBToHex(col), HSBToRGB(col));
```

To:

```
cal.data('colorpicker').onChange.apply(cal, [col, HSBToHex(col), HSBToRGB(col), cal.data('colorpicker').el]);
```

This works out great, each time it changes color i update the element.

Now i need to do something similar for the hide function. When its hidding id like to commit the changes to the database. I think i need to change the following line, but i cant seem to get the correct reference to the element.

From

```
if (ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').onHide.apply(this, [ev.data.cal.get(0)]) != false)
```

To

```
if (ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').onHide.apply(this, [ev.data.cal.get(0),MY_ELEMENT]) != false)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right, where i have MY_ELEMENT change it to ev.data.cal.data('colorpicker').el